# SQL query optimization

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a set of simple Update queries which run in a transaction, each query update a particular table. the problem is if the table have records in thousands it results in time out error. any Idea how can I optimize this.

```
update DocumentPermission set ReferenceID = @MergeToUserID where ReferenceID=@SourceUserID

update BlogCategoryPermission set ReferenceID = @MergeToUserID where ReferenceID =SourceUserID

update BlogPermission set ReferenceID = @MergeToUserID where ReferenceID = @SourceUserID
```

Thanx

Comment: Do you have any update triggers on those 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You may just be missing an index for your ReferenceID column?  If it's having to comb through that table several times, it could be slow for you.